# Swift return to preview UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift

I have VC like a "Something went wrong". This VC i created like a separately VC(without storyboard) and i want to show it where i want. But in the "Something went wrong" View Controller i have a button "refresh". When a user click to this button he must to go back.

When i have some problem with parsing Json or something like this, i call Something went wrong" View Controller like this:

```
let navController = UINavigationController()

        navController.pushViewController(SomethingWentWorngVC(nibName: "SomethingWentWorngView", bundle: nil), animated: false)

        window?.rootViewController = navController
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

also i have extension for getting `window`

```
extension UIViewController {
     var appDelegate: AppDelegate {
     return UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
 }
 
 var sceneDelegate: SceneDelegate? {
     guard let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene,
         let delegate = windowScene.delegate as? SceneDelegate else { return nil }
      return delegate
 }
}

extension UIViewController {
 var window: UIWindow? {
     if #available(iOS 13, *) {
         guard let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene,
             let delegate = windowScene.delegate as? SceneDelegate, let window = delegate.window else { return nil }
                return window
     }
     
     guard let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate, let window = delegate.window else { return nil }
     return window
 }
}
```

in the `SomethingWentWorngVC` i have button for go to back

```
@IBAction func refreshAction(_ sender: Any) {
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)

}
```

but it doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this alternate way you can use this ,  initially u need to create the common code in appdelegate using tag, then you need to  do the addsubview to window for example,

for show

```
func showWentWrongScreen(){
        let getVC = SomethingWentWorngVC
                      if let getWindow = self.window {
                          getVC.view.tag = 501
                          getVC.view.frame = getWindow.bounds
                          getWindow.addSubview(getVC.view)
                      }
    }
```

for remove

```
func removeWentWrongScreen(){
    if let getWindow = self.window, let getWentWrongView = getWindow.viewWithTag(501){
        getWentWrongView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

now you can use where u need